# Separar string en substrings - Ideas para hacer este problema

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla con dos campos:     NumeroOrden | Texto

El campo texto es del tipo text. En él, las subcadenas se repiten con algunas diferencias.

Ejemplo:

NumeroOrden | TextoTexto

1          | 'COD AAA abc&COD BBBB def&COD C ghi&'

2          | 'COD DDDDDD abc&COD EEEEEEE def&'
 .
 .

Cada código empieza con COD y termina con el caracter ampersand (&).

Puede haber uno o mas COD dentro de un mismo registro.

Entre el COD y el & puede haber cualquier cantidad de caracteres.

Existe alguna forma de hacer una consulta para que me devuelva cada subcadena en un registro distinto?

Ejemplo:

```
      NumeroOrden           |  Texto

              1                COD AAA abc&
              1                COD BBBB def&
              1                COD C ghi&
              2                COD DDDDDD abc&
              2                COD EEEEEEE def&
```

Estoy usando sql server 2012.
Ideas de como se podría hacer?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Existen múltiples maneras de separar strings en sql. Todas con códigos, con algún tipo de complejidad, siempre que no se recurra a cursores.

Una de ellas es la función creada por Jeff Moden delimitedSplit8k

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l;
```

[Documentación sobre delimited Split 8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

El funcionamiento una vez creada la función es muy simple.

```
create table cadenas
             (
             id    int
           , texto text
             );
go
Insert into cadenas(id, texto)
values 
(1,'COD AAA abc&COD BBBB def&COD C ghi&'),
(2, 'COD DDDDDD abc&COD EEEEEEE def&' );
go
```

Con el escenario tal cuál lo has definido.

```
SELECT c.id as NumeroOrden, fn.Item 
FROM 
cadenas C CROSS APPLY
DBO.DelimitedSplit8K(C.texto, '&') fn
WHERE fn.item <> ''
```

Se invoca a la función con el operador Apply y pasando como parámetros la columna de la tabla y el separador.

[image: Resultado]

---

Otra opción es utilizar la función ufn_inline_split_me. (No puedo poner un enlace al código fuente creador de la misma, porque desconozco quién la creo, pero a mi me la hicieron llegar tal cual la expongo).

Ya que esta función llama primero a la función getNums creada por Itzik Ben-Gan

[GetNums](https://tsql.solidq.com/SourceCodes/GetNums.txt)

Qué te sirve para devolver números entre un rango.

```
GO
-- Itzik's VATN
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_GetNums]
(@low AS bigint, @high AS bigint) 
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
WITH
L0 AS (SELECT c FROM (VALUES(1),(1)) AS D(c)),
L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
L4 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
L5 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
(SELECT NULL)) AS rownum FROM L5)
SELECT TOP(@high - @low + 1) @low + rownum - 1 AS n
FROM Nums
ORDER BY rownum
);

GO

-- Erland's split_me
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_inline_split_me]
(
@param nvarchar(MAX), 
@delimiter nchar(1) = N','
)
RETURNS table AS
RETURN (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n) AS pos,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),
    SUBSTRING(@param, n,
    CHARINDEX(@delimiter, 
        @param + CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), 
    @delimiter), n) - n)))) 
    AS Value
FROM
    dbo.ufn_GetNums(1, LEN(@param))
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), @delimiter) 
   + @param, n, 1) 
    = @delimiter
);
GO
```

Una vez tienes ambas creadas y con el mismo escenario, la resolución es igual de simple.

```
SELECT c.id as NumeroOrden, fn.Value as Texto
FROM 
cadenas C CROSS APPLY
dbo.ufn_inline_split_me(c.texto,'&') fn
```

En esta, no hace falta aplicar el where porque la misma evita la devolución de resultados sin contenido.

[image: Salida]

Comment: Wow. Muchas gracias!!! Me ayudaste un montón!!!